# Unable to open camera in window 8 store app using c#

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I am the beginner on window 8 store app,still i am working on the app in which i have to open camera and capture the image, but when i try to execute following line of code, its throws following exception.

I am using following line of code

```
Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
```

And  throwing following exception

```
Requested Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI' is not registered.
```

Please advise
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you are on an emulator? Can you reproduce the error on a real device?

Comment: i am running on window 8 machine and web cam also installed there

Comment: Maybe this post here can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525363/use-mediacapture-on-a-windows-8-desktop-app

Comment: still  same error on  "var capture = new MediaCapture();"

Comment: Anyone is there?I need help in this issue.